# GLUT timer loop stopping prematurely

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I've encountered a strange issue where `glutTimerFunc` seems to randomly stop working when I call it with a zero delay.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int x = 0;

void init(void) 
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.125, 0.875, -1.0, 1.0);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1.0, x ? 1.0 : 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int value)
{
    x = !x;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0); // The line in question
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this to show a flickering square, that is changing color as fast as the GPU can keep up.

That is what it actually does initially, but the timer loop seems to randomly stop, and the square stops changing color. Sometimes it doesn't flicker perceptibly at all, and sometimes it flickers for several seconds before stopping.

It doesn't stop if I set the delay to 1ms (`glutTimerFunc(1, timer, 0);`).

Why does the timer loop stop unexpectedly?

I don't really care about how to fix it, just why it happens.

Comment: Insert output statements in both `timer` and `display` functions. Do you really observe that calls to either one stop after a few seconds?

Comment: @n.m. Inserting a `printf` in the `timer` function seems to prevent the timer from stopping, or at least slow it down quite a bit. A `printf` in `display` does stop though, and observing `x` in a separate function does show that it has stopped. I'm positive the timer stops.

Comment: Well, it never stops for me. Interestingly, `timer` is called much more often than `display` (for me again), there's no guarantee that each flip of `x` will be followed by a redisplay. If you want that, schedule a redisplay from `display` (that is, `timer` calls `glutPostRedisplay` and `display` calls `glutTimerFunc`).

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU is changing the value faster than your monitor can draw it.

If you had a monitor with an extremely high refresh rate, you could probably see it, but unfortunately we're limited to 60Hz/120Hz/240Hz for now.

When you remove the 1ms forced delay, you are causing the system to become a non-deterministic system (based on the speed of other programs, rather than just yours), and that's why you're getting the random behavior.

Comment: See my comment on the question. I've pretty much determined that the timer loop actually stops.

Comment: The timer stop doesn't seem to be dependent on display code either.